# Bootstrap theming only Modal component

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, theming

I've been trying to build a customize bootstrap theme without success. I want just the Modal component. For that, I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I did the following:

1. I installed bootstrap library through NPM within my project
   (simple web page)
2. Created 2 css files: mine.css and mine.scss.
3. Imported the necessary (I think) modules for just Modal component.
4. I run the code "sass mine.scsss mine.css" into the shell

Then it works, but not the transition effect. It seems like something is missing. Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mine.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-title="New Data">MORE INFORMATION</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">More information</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Coming soon!
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mine.scss

```
// Required
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Modal
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/4aLifeTime/pen/abyWxPO).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/scss/_transitions.scss because it hosts the fade class modals are using

The classes used are `.fade` `.fade.in` and `.show`